# Open different pages in iframe using a loop

Tags: loops, iframe, wait

I want to open different pages in iframe with loop, following is the structure i want

for i loop 10 times
{
 iframe open url: "abc.com/i"
 wait for 1 minute
}

i want a code to do the above mentioned, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a empty iframe and change it's src attribute using javascript.

HTML:

```
   <iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
   setInterval(changeIframeSrc,1000); // every 1min

   function changeIframeSrc() {
        var iframe = window.frames["myFrame"];
        iframe.src = "your_link_here";
   }
```

Comment: instead of window.frames["myFrame"] use document.getElementById("myFrame") and change the name attribute into id in the html.